# STRIPE Checkout session Invoice : session.invoice is null in the response object whereas i enabled invoice_creation in stripe.checkout.sessions.create

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, checkout, deno, invoice

invoice id of a checkout session response is null even if i enabled invoice_creation in the request object. It worked before, i was able to get this id but now i get a null value. I need this invoice id to allow the customer to download his invoice in PDF Format.

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
            payment_method_types: ['card'],
            line_items: lineItems,
            mode: 'payment',
            success_url: 'http://localhost:80/OBV/success',
            cancel_url: 'http://localhost:80/OBV/cancel',
            invoice_creation: {
                enabled: true,
                
            },

          });

          const retrievedSession = session.id;
          console.log('retrieved session : ' + retrievedSession);
          const sessionInvoice = session.invoice;
          console.log('session Invoice : ' + sessionInvoice);
```

And here is the response i get in the console :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ja43h.jpg)

So how can i get this invoice id from this checkout session ?

[EDIT 1] : In response of @Tarzan comment :

Now i put the retrieved requests after the Checkout session is completed, after loading the success page :

```js
const successPage = async(ctx:any)=>{

    try{
        
        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(
            retrievedSession
          );
          console.log('session id : ' + session.id);
          
           const sessionInvoice = session.invoice;
          console.log('session Invoice : '+ sessionInvoice);

          const invoice = await stripe.invoices.retrieve(
            sessionInvoice
          );

          const invoicePdf = invoice.invoice_pdf;
          console.log('invoice pdf url : '+ invoicePdf);
        
         /* ctx.cookies.set('invoice_pdf', invoicePdf);*/

        ctx.render('./OBV/checkout/success.ejs',{Voyant: true, invoiceUrl: 'Empty'});
        console.log('success page reached !');
    }catch(err) {
        ctx.response.status = 200;
            ctx.response.body = {
                success: false,
                msg: err.toString()
            }
    }finally{
        
        await client.end();
    }
```

And i get the same null value response for session.invoice and this message is displayed on my screen :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOIJz.jpg)

[EDIT 2]

```js
const successPage = async(ctx:any)=>{

    try{
        
         const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(retrievedSession,{expand: ["invoice"]});

         console.log('session invoice : ' + session.invoice);

        ctx.render('./OBV/checkout/success.ejs',{Voyant: true, invoiceUrl: 'Empty'});
        
        console.log('success page reached !');
    }catch(err) {
        ctx.response.status = 200;
            ctx.response.body = {
                success: false,
                msg: err.toString()
            }
    }finally{
        
        await client.end();
    }
    
};
```

logs:

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOIJz.jpg)

retrievedSession is the id of the session

Comment: Are you running this in the frontend or the backend?

Comment: running this from the backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete @Tarzan answer in order to retrieve some useful informations that you want back like invoices links you need to set up a webhook, there is a documentation in your stripe dashborad when you go to "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/webhooks", they explain you how to set up an endpoint and the way they create their webhooks. I don't know why but i didn't need webhooks before, and it was working, but now i think that it's the only way to get some informations that didn't show up in a default response flow. If you want more details about i converted their node js explanations into deno oak let me know

Answer (score 0):

The invoice won't be created before the Checkout Session is complete. It seems you're trying to access the invoice field upon creation. This is an expected result.

EDIT:
I think you're facing some kind of race condition. Let me explain:

Normally the Invoice creation happens asynchronously, and before the Checkout Session has been fully completed (the invoice has been created and assigned to the Checkout Session), your customer is redirected to the success page. A quick fix would be to setup a webhook endpoint that listens to `checkout.session.completed`. This is a very good practice for several reasons

1. This is the best way to fulfill your Checkout orders as explained [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders)
2. By doing so you will be able to [wait](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#:%7E:text=Your%20webhook%20endpoint%20redirects%20your%20customer%20to%20the%20success_url%20when%20you%20acknowledge%20you%20received%20the%20event.%20In%20scenarios%20where%20your%20endpoint%20is%20down%20or%20the%20event%20isn%E2%80%99t%20acknowledged%20properly%2C%20your%20handler%20redirects%20the%20customer%20to%20the%20success_url%2010%20seconds%20after%20a%20successful%20payment)
   until the `checkout.session.completed` has been sent to your webhook endpoint before redirecting the customer to your success page, by which time the invoice should be populated.

On a separate but also related note, having the `retrievedSession` as a global variable is a terrible idea, and you shouldn't be using it at all for concurrency reasons. Instead you should be using the Checkout Session ID [passed](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page#modify-success-url) to your success page instead.

Comment: in the first section of code i shared where there is const session, we can see that const retrievedsession value is taken from the object response and is session.id so session.invoice just shoudn't be null. in this order checkout session is completed and if it was not completed i shouldn't be able to have a session.id value ... Am i wrong ?

Comment: when you create the Checkout Session, at first, there's no Invoice attached to that session. The Checkout Session has an ID upon creation. Only when the Checkout Session is completed (the customer has entered successfully their payment method info) that the Invoice gets created.

Comment: now i moved some lines :  retrieved requests are fired after sucesspage is rendered ( ctx.render ) meaning checkout session is commpleted, but i get the same result ... It worked well before, i could get invoice id, and the link to the invoice pdf, i dont know why it suddenly stopped working ... However i still get the invoice being created in the my dashboard with the pdf link, invoice id, etc ...

Comment: but how are you getting `retrievedSession` if it's not passed through the `ctx`?

Comment: and btw you don't have to make 2 API calls. you can just do it like so
`const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(id,{expand: ["invoice"]});`

Comment: i created an empty let variable retrievedSession outside routes functions, so i can bring data from a function to an other, by providing the needed value to this variable inside a function and call it in an other function ... i could simply do the same with cookies

Comment: ok for using on call like you said instead of two but i'm still getting null value

Comment: what can you see in the logs?

Comment: same thing, session.invoice is null. i edited the question, look at it

Comment: at this point, I'm pretty sure there's a race condition happening somewhere. Do you have a webhook endpoint setup? https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders

Comment: No webhooks for the moment, i planed to use them later in my integration but as i said earlier it worked before, i'll read documentation again maybe i miss something or they changed something that cause the need  of other values in the checkout session request ... I'll go back later with the answer

Comment: have you read my edit? You need to create a webhook endpoint. That's the only way to overcome the race condition.

Comment: I have just read your edit, i'll modify like you said

Comment: So i finally succeded to retrieve the invoice pdf link ! as you said i needed to set up a webhook ...  i struggled to find a way especially to convert node js explanations in deno. Thats was the jungle, thanks to answered me @Tarzan